# How to get data from getDefaultCountMode into my controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using default count mode in manifest.json

```
    "mainService_SRV": {
            "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/mainService_SRV/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Inline"
            }
        },
```

As a result I am able to get the total number of records in my batch file, like this:
[total number of records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEdAC.png)

Now, I want to use this count into my controller. I tried with the following code
`this.getView().getModel("model_Name").getDefaultCountMode()`

But getting an error *getDefaultCountMode is not a function.*

An idea how can it be accessed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The getDefaultCountMode method will return the default count mode for retrieving the count of collections. It does not return the count of records for any EntitySet. It is used internally by SAPUI5 controls like Lists, Tables, Charts. The count computed by these controls is not directly available through the framework. You could probably check the binding length for the count. If you are using a List control, you could attach a updateFinished event & get the total record count in the event's parameters.